# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un balón y una pelota?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

Ya sé que una pelota es de béisbol y un balón es de baloncesto. ¿Qué palabra es para vóleibol, fútbol, tenis, y los otros deportes? ¿Y por qué?

Comment: Yo creo que este uso es regional. En Chile se acostumbra a decirle *pelota* a todo: *pelota de fútbol/tennis/voleibol*. Aunque se hacen distinciones para otros deportes como *balón de baloncesto.*

Comment: De acuerdo con @Ustanak. Personalmente, uso pelota para los de tamaño sófbol e inferior que suelen ser duros, y balón para los tamaños superiores que suelen ser hinchados y (relativamente) blandos. Eso dicho, no me llamaría la atención si alguien usase la otra palabra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La diferencia consiste en que un balón es aquel que se puede inflar, es decir, que tiene una válvula a través de la cual es posible inflarlo, por ejemplo, el balón utilizado en fútbol, basketball, volleyball, futbol americano, etc. Por otro lado, una pelota no se puede inflar, ya tiene un tamaño y forma predefinidas, tal es el caso de las pelotas de golf, tenis, cricket, ping pong, etc.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Hay que aclarar que en algunas partes las pelotas pueden ser tanto infladas como sólidas, es decir que _pelota_ es hiperónimo de _balón_ (al menos en Chile ocurre así). Y quiero comentar que el sentido original de la palabra  _balón_ era precisamente "pelota", pero que adquirió el sentido de "inflada" por contaminación con el inglés _balloon_ (que tiene la misma raíz _bala_ pero que evolucionó hacia otro lado). De hecho en otros ámbitos hay balones "contenedores de gas" que no son esféricos ni se usan para jugar.

Comment: @Rodrigo Excelente apunte. En realidad yo también me quedé pensando en las pelotas de playa, por ejemplo, ya que se pueden inflar pero nos referimos a ellas como "pelota", es el caso particular de México, no estoy seguro de su uso en otros paises.

Comment: En España también es común decir "pelota de playa" o "pelota de fitness", ambas inflables.

Comment: Es extraño; yo también pienso que **balón** se refiere a cuando puede inflarse y **pelota** no; pero la RAE no da ninguna referencia a este aspecto.

Answer (score 4):

Como licenciado en Educación Física me gustaría aportar mi punto de vista.

El balón es aquel que tiene una cámara de aire interior y una cubierta exterior, ejemplo el de fútbol.
Pelota son las que se hinchan pero no tienen cámara interior. Solo una capa. Ejemplo: baloncesto, *voley*, etc.
Bola son las que tienen un componente macizo y no pueden variar su tamaño. Ejemplo: bolos, *baseball*, billar, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No es algo exacto, pero es más bien por el tamaño (al menos en España). Se dice pelota de golf, pelota de tenis, pelota de ping pong, pero sin embargo es balón de fútbol, balón de baloncesto, etc.

Comment: No obstante no es extraño escuchar pelota de fútbol

Comment: Es verdad, a veces se dice una "pelota" de fútbol, pero suele referirse más bien a una pelota de juguete, con la que juegan los niños. Cuando se habla del balón reglamentario, suele decirse "balón".

Comment: No es sólo el tamaño. Los jugadores de rugby nunca hablan de la pelota, sino del balón, porque una pelota siempre es redonda.

Answer (score 2):

He sabido que la diferencia entre balón y pelota, es que una (el balon) tiene contacto directo con un segmento del deportista (ejemplos: fútbol, voley, baloncesto, rugby, etc.). En cambio, en la otra (la pelota) hay un objeto entre ella y el segmento del cuerpo para poder golpearla (ejemplos: golf, la raqueta en el tenis o en el tenis de mesa, el bate en béisbol).

Answer (score 0):

Según mi concepción, la diferencia no radica precisamente si se puede inflar o no, sino más bien en un tema conceptual, es decir, balón es aquel que se utiliza directamente con contacto al cuerpo o segmentos, sin embargo, en el caso de la pelota su utilización es mediante un implementó entre el jugador o participante y el objeto en cuestión, es así como tenemos, el balón de basquetbol, futbol, voleibol, Rugby, Balonmano, etc.

Los que se utilizan en contacto directo con el cuerpo de quién lo utiliza, a diferencia de la pelota que es mediante un implementó que hace las veces de intermediario entre el participante y el objeto, cómo lo son pelota de tenis, tenis de mesa, golf, beisbol, los que utilizan respectivamente raqueta, paleta, palos de golf, etc.

Al menos esa es la concepción que aprendí en mi formación profesional y que considero más acertada y sencilla al distinguir ambos casos.